# Swift Firestore - How to check if queried users' id have been added to field?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im working on an online dating app and I'm trying to query users who's ID haven't been added to a field of the current logged in user.

My User model:

- id: String
- blocked: Array of user ID's
- liked: Array of user ID's
- didntLike: Array of user ID's

Observer:

- potentialMatches: Array of Users // this will be shown for the logged in user to pick from

Essentially when the logged in user makes a choice the other user's ID gets added to one of the arrays. The problem I'm having is I need to filter users so they don't get added or re-added when making a query. Basically I want to retrieve 10 users who haven't blocked or swiped on. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's what I have for the function so far

```
func GetPotentialMatches()
{
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collection("users").document(uid!)

    ref.whereField("id", isNotEqualTo: uid!).limit(to: 10).getDocuments{ (snap, error) in
        if(error != nil)
        {
            print("error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
        
        // if user id is not contained in blocked, liked, or didntLike array add to potentialMatches array
        // self.potentialMatches.append(User)
    }
}
```

Comment: "Basically I want to retrieve 10 users who haven't blocked or swiped on." Your code doesn't seem to do anything towards this yet. Did you check the page on [query operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) already to see which would apply here?